# How to change background color for only part of a label - ASPX?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a label and I have given some default text for it. On button click, the label gets appended with some number that was automatically generated. I know how to change the background-color for the entire label, but I don't know how to change for only part of the label.

I want to highlight only that number. Is that possible?

Comment: Use two labels and an appropriate CSS-class on the number-label.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

Sample.aspx

```
<asp:Label ID="lblTest" runat="server" Text="this is the number : ">    </asp:Label>
```

Code behind

```
int inValue =  Convert.ToInt32(strValue); /* Programatically getting values here in **strValues** */
lblTest.Text += "<span style=\"color: red;\">" + inValue.ToString() + "</span>";
```

Comment: By default asp.net will html-encode that, and you'll get `&lt;` instead of a left angle bracket to start the span element.

Answer (score 0):

Use an `<asp:Literal>` instead of `<asp:Label>`. This will allow you to set the raw HTML content of the control, which can include a `span` styled in a different color for part of the text. But at this point your *are* building the html in code.

Answer (score 0):

Use 2 labels with CSS Style - background.

Example:

```
<asp:Label ID="label1" runat="server" Text="text" Width="100%" Style="background:#EEEEEE;"></asp:Label>

<asp:Label ID="label1" runat="server" Text="text" Width="100%" Style="background:#EEFFEE;"></asp:Label>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can wrap the number part of the label that you want highlighted in a `<span>`.

Then set the `<span>` style background-color to whatever color you want, with the help of CSS or inline like this:

```
<span style="background-red;">Number</span>
```

Comment: This isn't really applicable when writing ASP.NET